# Declared Variables Not Being Recognized When Setting New Variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to write a SET query using the value assigned to the initial @period variable, but the variable is not being recognized in the SET. How can I make it so that I only need to declare period once?

When I declare @period within the SET, the correct output is shown. However, I need there to just be a single @period declaration at the top that will work with multiple SET.

```
DECLARE @period VARCHAR(15) = '01/01/2018'
SET @SQL = 'SELECT col1, col2, right(@period,4) + left(@period,2)
            FROM table' 
print(@SQL)
exec(@SQL)
```

ERROR: Must declare the scalar variable "@period".

Output is needed

Comment: You need to use sp_executesql to pass parameters in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Also you aren't declaring @Sql in your question code.

Comment: Although I've posted an answer, why are you using `EXEC` in the first place here? Your entire SQL is a literal value, so you don't need `EXEC` or `sp_executesql`.

Comment: It's dynamic, the question was just simplified for assistance. Thank you both for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use dynamic SQL.  I would recommend:

```
DECLARE @period VARCHAR(15) = '01/01/2018';

SET @SQL = N'SELECT col1, col2, right(@period,4) + left(@period,2)
            FROM table' ;

print(@SQL)

exec sp_executesql @sql, '@period varchar(15)', @period=@period;
```

Make sure that `@sql` is declared as `NVARCHAR()`.

Answer (score 2):

Variables are only able to be referenced in the context, and batch they are declared. If you are using "Dynamic" SQL (there's nothing dynamic about your SQL) the statement is run in a separate context and can't be referenced. For example:

```
DECLARE @i int = 1;
EXEC (N'SELECT @i;');
```

You need to pass the values to the dynamic SQL as parameters using `sp_executesql`. For example:

```
DECLARE @i int = 1;
EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT @n;', N'@n int', @n = @i;
```